# Compile error in std::find_if

Tags: c++, ptr-vector

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong here?

```
class Base_Type
{
public:     
    string name;    
    int localType;
};

boost::ptr_vector<Base_Type> tVector; 

struct findVariable
{
    findVariable(const string& name) : _name(name) {};
    const string& _name;

    bool operator () (const Base_Type& arg) const
    {
        return (_name == arg.name);
    }
};

typedef boost::ptr_vector<Base_Type>::iterator tVector_it; 

inline tVector_it findVariable(string& _name) 
{
    return find_if(tVector.begin(), tVector.end(), findVariable(_name));        
}
```

Compile Error:

> ...\vc\include\algorithm(43): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
>
> ...\vc\include\algorithm(54): note: see reference to function template
>   instantiation '_InIt std::_Find_if<_Iter,_Pr>(_InIt,_InIt,_Pr)' being
>   compiled    with    [
>           _InIt=boost::void_ptr_iterator>>,var_T::Base_Type>,
>           _Iter=boost::void_ptr_iterator>>,var_T::Base_Type>,
>           _Pr=var_T::tVector_it       ]

Comment: Not sure about the compilation error, but the `_name` member is a **dangling reference**, giving you UB at run-time, so that's one thing you're "doing wrong here".

Comment: The compiler error is a bit fishy: `_Pr=var_T::tVector_it` tells me that for the compiler `findVariable(_name)` results in an object of `var_T::tVector_it`. Certainly not, unless you obmit code where you maybe define a function with the same name.. oh yes you do

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: How is that a danging reference? It could potentially be a dangling reference if the class is used improperly, but it doesn't seem to be here.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: In general, not in this particular usage where the temporary it refers to lasts, as usual, till the end of the full-expression. I should have used the word "potential". Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a structure named `findVariable`, then you have a function named `findVariable`.

In the function, when you do `findVariable(_name)` you don't create an instance of structure, you call the function recursively. And the function does not return something you can use as a predicate to `std::find_if` so the compiler gives you an error.

Simple solution? Rename your structure, or your function.

Answer (score 1):

`findVariable` is both the name of your function and the name of the struct you want to create an object with when you call `findVariable(_name)` within you `find_if` statement.

Simply rename one of them, for instance:

```
struct findVariableHelper
{
    findVariableHelper(const string& name) : _name(name) {};
    const string _name;

    bool operator () (const Base_Type& arg) const
    {
        return (_name == arg.name);
    }
};

typedef boost::ptr_vector<Base_Type>::iterator tVector_it; 

inline tVector_it findVariable(string& _name) 
{
    return find_if(tVector.begin(), tVector.end(), findVariableHelper(_name));        
}
```

Comment: Fixed the dangling reference / UB for you. Not that it would have manifested in this code. But still.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Thanks, I just did a silly copy/paste and renamed the function....but does it really make a difference as `_name` from `findVariable` function remains valid and alive during the whole `find_if` code execution...?

Comment: No, it doesn't manifest in this code. And my fix didn't include the `move` optimization. Uhm, I think that's it. ;-)